# catkin check runtime dependency

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does this exist?

The use case is packages which provide `cmake/xxx-extras.cmake` files. An obvious example is the message_generation macros throwing a warning/error if you didn't run_depend on message_runtime, but there are similar cases where a build_depend package provides a macro which does something in a dependent package that will then need some other run_depend.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98751/catkin-check-runtime-dependency/) by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1153 on 2013-11-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you referring to the following error message of catkin: https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/groovy-devel/cmake/catkin_package.cmake#L214 ?

It uses the CMake variable `${PROJECT_NAME}_RUN_DEPENDS` which is available after you invoked `catkin_package()` (or `catkin_package_xml()`). It provides all the keys for run_depend from the package.xml file.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2013-11-15**:
Fantastic, that was just what I was looking for.